# Как выделить другим цветом определенный текст в TextView?

Tags: android, android-textview

Имеется `TextView` в котором нужно выделить другим цветом все буквы до первой запятой. Хочу выделить обращение к нику в чате.

Сейчас стоит два `TextView`, но решение костыльное и выглядит не очень, так как текст сообщения справа, а нужно обтекание вокруг обращения.

Все таки нужен способ покрасить текст в одном `TextView`. Как? Даже не знаю, не могу привести код попытки, так как элементарно, не знаю как это реализовать

**UPD**

Слышал о `html` кодах, но не пойму как это использовать, если длина обращения неизвестна (до первой запятой)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Spannable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
 Spannable word = new SpannableString("Your message");        

 word.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 TV.setText(word);
 Spannable wordTwo = new SpannableString("Your new message");        

 wordTwo.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, wordTwo.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 TV.append(wordTwo);
```

Можно через html например

```
<string name="signal_msg3">
        <![CDATA[
        Добавьте номера Ваших близких в <font color=\'#cc0000\'>Экстренные контакты</font>
        ]]>
</string>
```

И `TV.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.signal_msg3)));`